# how can I have a dynamic persistence unit name?

Tags: jpa, jakarta-ee, jta, payara, persistence.xml

I have an application, written in JEE, JPA, I use Payara as the application server.

In my application's persistence.xml I have

`<persistence-unit name="XYZ" transaction type="JTA" >`

On the payara side, I have JDBC resource called XYZ, with JDBC connection Pool.
The database used by the application is dedicated to one customer.

Now I want to deploy this app (unchanged) to other customers (on the same server), each customer needs separate database. In order to achieve that I need to modify persistence unit name for each customer and recompile the app, and of course, define JDBC on the Payara side.

I would like to somehow have this persistence unit name being dynamic, so I don't have to recompile the app for each customer. Is there any simple way to achieve that?
In the worst case, I can just modify persistence.xml in the compiled war file, but I hope a more elegant solution exists.

Please advise how to solve that issue.

Comment: Maybe you can map the same dastasource name to a different database per deployment, to drop the need to change the persistence unit name?

Answer (score 0):

You can setup a own Instance inside Payara for every customer and deploy your Program to these Instances.
Then you're able to set a variable, different for each Instance.
This variable can than be used inside your persistence.xml.

Using variables is documentated here:
https://docs.payara.fish/community/docs/documentation/payara-server/server-configuration/var-substitution/README.html